# A problem on progression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a,b,c are in arithmetic progression., p,q,r in harmonic progression and ap,bq,cr are in geometric progression., then $\frac{p}{r}+\frac{r}{p} = $ ?

**EDIT:** I have tried to use the basic/standard properties of the respective progressions to get the desired result, but I am not yet successful.

Answer (score 3):

Let's represent your arithmetic progression as

$$a,a+h,a+2h$$

where $h=b-a$

and your harmonic progression as

$$p,\frac{p}{l+1},\frac{p}{2l+1},$$

(following [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_progression_%28mathematics%29))

and the condition that the products of corresponding terms of the arithmetic and harmonic sequences form a geometric sequence implies

$$\frac{a+h}{a(l+1)}=\frac{a+2h}{a+h}\frac{l+1}{2l+1}$$

Since

$$\frac{p}{r}+\frac{r}{p}=2l+1+\frac1{2l+1}$$

we solve for $l$, which has two solutions.

I leave the rest to you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $\rm\:\ \quad\displaystyle \frac{p}r+\frac{r}p\ =\ \frac{(p+r)^2}{pr} - 2$

But we have that$\rm\quad\displaystyle p\:r\ =\ \frac{(bq)^2}{ac}\ \ $ via $\rm\ ap,\:bq,\:cr\ $ geometric

and we have $\rm\quad\ \ \displaystyle p+r\ =\ \frac{2pr}q\quad\ \ \ $ via $\rm\ p,q,r\ $ harmonic

Answer (score 0):

If a,b,c are in arithmetic progression, then you can write them as a, a+d, a+2d.  Maybe all you need is 2b=a+c.  Similarly for geometric progression, you can write them as ap, apz, apz^2 where z is the common ration (often we use r, but that was taken).  Again, maybe (bq)^2=ap*cr is all you need.

Comment: I knew this relations and I tried to use them but not quite successful.